# Understanding limits of integration

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, step-function

I have a question on limits of integration.
The exercise is as follows:

Give an example of a step function f, defined on the closed interval `[0,5]`, which has the following properties:

$$\int_0^2 f(x) \,dx= 5$$
$$\int_0^5 f(x) \,dx= 2$$

One solution is given as:

$$f(x) =  \frac52$$ if $$0 <= x < 2$$

and

$$f(x) = -1$$ if $$2 <= x <= 5$$

My question is: Would the following answer also be true?

$$f(x) =  \frac52$$ if $$0 <= x <= 2$$

and

$$f(x) = -1$$ if $$2 < x <= 5$$

Comment: Yes, that is fine too.